# How to make the previous label disappear and be released?

Tags: iphone, uilabel, cgpoint

How to make the previous "label box" disappear and be released?
I release the object but it still just creates new "label boxes" on top of "label boxes" when I tap and move.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    CGPoint nowPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint prevPoint = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self.view];

    CGRect RectFrame1;
    RectFrame1 = CGRectMake(nowPoint.x, nowPoint.y, 280, 30);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:RectFrame1];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x %f   y %f", nowPoint.x, nowPoint.y];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    [label release];
    //[self release];
    //[&RectFrame1 release];
}
```

Comment: jdl, you've been around for a week, and asked a handful of questions. It's time you learned how to format the code in your questions, so we don't have to clean it up for you.  http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I just started this morning.  But I will try and learn from your link how to format code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove it from the view use `removeFromSuperview`

```
[urlabel removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Thank you... keeping track of the address and releasing as you specified, in the beginning, prior to new instance works.

Answer (score 0):

What you exactly mean to do. Do you want to remove the label. 
`[label release]` will release the instance from memory not from the view.
`[label removeFromSuperview]` will remove from view. But adding it to superview and then removing it immediately seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self removeChild:label cleanup:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are displaying each touched point on a label. You can solve the issue by modifying your code...

```
CGRect RectFrame1;
UILabel * label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:111];
//Here 111 is used you can use your own tags
if(label==nil){   

    RectFrame1 = CGRectMake(nowPoint.x, nowPoint.y, 280, 30);
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:RectFrame1];    
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.tag = 111;//Adding tag to our label so that we can call it later.
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x %f   y %f", nowPoint.x, nowPoint.y];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    [label release];

} else {

    RectFrame1 = label.frame;
    RectFrame1.origin = CGPointMake(nowPoint.x, nowPoint.y);
    label.frame = RectFrame1;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x %f   y %f", nowPoint.x, nowPoint.y];

}
```

Hope this helps you .... :)

Comment: Thank you... I did something similar with an integer variable to track the address of the pointer.  But it is nice to see other ways.